# Why Does Running A Simple Query In Parallel Make It Faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing, oracle-sqldeveloper

If we look at a simple query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER2;
```

We can tell by looking at it that it simply does one thing, retrieves everything from CUSTOMER2.

Now my question is, why is it that when we run it like this:

```
SELECT/*+ PARALLEL(CUSTOMER2, 8) */ * FROM CUSTOMER2;
```

The cost of it (according to execution plan) goes from 581 to 81? Since its only one task, isn't it just performed on the same thread anyway?

I can understand if there were two full table scans needing to be done as you can run those two in parallel threads so they execute at the same time. But in our case, there is only one full table scan.

So how does running it in parallel make it faster when there is nothing to run it "in parallel" with?

Lastly, when I altered my personal cluster and the one table to run in parallel when anything is performed on it I did not see any change in cost like I did with the small statement.

This is my personal one:

```
SELECT AVG(s.sellprice), s.qty, s.custid   
FROM CUSTOMER_saracl c, sale_saracl s 
WHERE c.custid = s.custid  
GROUP BY (s.qty,  s.custid)  
HAVING AVG(s.sellprice) >  
  (SELECT MIN(AVG(price))    
   FROM  product_saracl    
   WHERE pname  
   LIKE 'FA%'   
GROUP BY price);
```

Why would that be?

Thank you for any help, I just today learnt about parallel execution so go easy on me haha!

Comment: With your query hint you are forcing Oracle to break up the one task into 8 tasks, which run in parallel, each collecting 1/8 of the results, and then to merge the final result set to return to you. It is entirely possible that forcing parallelization will actually create _more_ work for the database (because of the overhead required to manage the parallel processes) and take longer to complete than not using it, especially for relatively small tables. Make sure you have current table statistics collected on all tables involved in your queries.

Comment: That makes a ton more sense. However, according to the CBO the cost stays the exact same so it does not look its affecting it at all. With the required overhead I would expect to see somewhat of a difference. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Good starting [point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/parallel-exec-intro.html#GUID-ADDF75ED-8CBE-4544-B59E-283A093A3337)

Answer (score 1):

One very important point about relational databases is that tables represent *unordered* sets.  That means that the pages that are scanned for a table can be scanned in any order.

Oracle actually takes advantage of this for parallel scans of a single table.  There is additional overhead to bring the results back together, which is why the estimated cost is 81 and not 73 (581 / 8).

I think this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#:%7E:text=Oracle%20Database%20divides%20the%20operation,degree%20of%20parallelism%20(DOP).) has good examples that explain this.  Some are quite close to your query.

Note that parallelism does not just apply to reading tables.  In fact, it is more commonly associated with other operations, such as joins, aggregation, and sorting.

Comment: Well, I just learnt something today! I never knew that the tables represent unordered sets. So I read a link sent to me by a commenter on this post and it said one of the most common ways of distribution between producers and consumers is Hash Distribution. "This distribution attempts to divide the work equally among consumers based on hash values.". Does that mean that it divides the job of doing a full scan into 8 parts (each producer/consumer does a 8th of the full scan) and then they all piece it together when its done? If that is the case, then why does the cost stay the same on my query?

Comment: I understand why on the simple query I originally posted it brings the cost down by that much as it is the original cost / 8 + the overhead required to "stich" it all back together. Yet, on my query one it does not bring the cost down at all.

Comment: @ExileVoid . . . The parallel execution needs to be triggered by the hint.  Otherwise, (on y9ur configuration) Oracle reserves only a single thread for such queries, assuming it needs other threads for concurrent executions.

Comment: /*+ PARALLEL(CUSTOMER_saracl, sale_saracl, product_saracl, 8) */. would I just add a hint like that? I assumed because I altered the table to add the parallel it would not require any hints. Thank you for all this help by the way, its much appreciated!!!